# GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion Error Got when using evnce comand to open pdf in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have tried to open a pdf Using Evince Command but somehow i got this message "GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed " Help me to know more detail about this warning message

Answer (score 0):

### use Below steps to solve the problem

First I downgraded libglib2.0-0 to some earlier version using the following procedure:

In the terminal type

Code:

apt-cache showpkg libglib2.0-0

Then it shows the versions that are available in my repositories.

Then I chose the next lower version and type
Code:

sudo aptitude install libglib2.0-0=version (something like 2.24.1-0ubuntu, depends on what is avaliable)

Then it downgrades ligglib2.0-0 and a bunch of other things and removed a few packages (most of them seem pretty useless)

Then I reinstalled an earlier version of evince and it didn't work. When trying to open a pdf document it said pdf type not supported. So I took a risk to upgrade evince again to the latest version (which gave me the troubles to begin with) by activating the source. libglib.2.0-0 also got upgraded and it installed a few additional packages. This time evince worked beautifully, seems a lot faster due to the upgrade.

icedtea-pluggin was removed during the downgrading and couldn't be reinstalled after the downgrading due to broken dependencies. But after the second upgrade I could reinstall it without problem.

So it all worked out in the end